# Best way to combine two dataframes by updating duplicate indices and outer join the rest

Tags: python, pandas, merge

what is the best way for me to combine the following two dataframes? I would like:

- `desired_df` to use prices from `new_df` for any duplicate `security`, `date` indices in `new_df` and `old_df` (i.e. update stock2 in example below)
- `desired_df` to retain any entries from `old_df` that do not appear in `new_df` (retain stock3)
- `desired_df` to include any entries from `new_df` that do not appear in `old_df` (add stock2)

Here is an example of what I am looking for:

```
old_df = pd.DataFrame({'security': ['stock1', 'stock3'],'date': ['2019-12-23', '2019-12-23'],'price':[10,9]}).set_index(['security','date'])

new_df = pd.DataFrame({'security': ['stock1', 'stock2'],'date': ['2019-12-23', '2019-12-24'],'price':[11,12]}).set_index(['security','date'])

desired_df = pd.DataFrame({'security': ['stock1', 'stock2', 'stock3'],'date': ['2019-12-23', '2019-12-24', '2019-12-23'],'price':[11,12,11]}).set_index(['security','date'])
```

Here are print-outs of `old_df`, `new_df` and my `desired_df`:

```
print(old_df)
                     price
security date             
stock1   2019-12-23     10
stock3   2019-12-23      9

print(new_df)

                     price
security date             
stock1   2019-12-23     11
stock2   2019-12-24     12

print(desired_df)
                     price
security date             
stock1   2019-12-23     11
stock2   2019-12-24     12
stock3   2019-12-23     9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
desired_df = new_df.combine_first(old_df)
```

---

```
                     price
security date             
stock1   2019-12-23   11.0
stock2   2019-12-24   12.0
stock3   2019-12-23    9.0
```